# how can I fix a Matlab CSVread error (file not found)?

Tags: matlab, path

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\brend\\mesonet\\2015USDA';
site = 'CLYD';

% Read data from txt files (Jan-Dec)
for i = 1:12
    if i<10
      raw_data = csvread([path,site,'150',num2str(i),'.txt']);
    else 
      raw_data = csvread([path,site,'15',num2str(i),'.txt']);
    end
end
```

Not sure how to fix this. should the file I want to read be a .txt or .csv? I have tried both and neither have worked. If I remove the hard brackets and only have 'path' in the parentheses it will locate it, but I need the code to be exactly like this for my project.

I am not sure what the site portion is supposed to do or why it could be messing it up.

Comment: What are the names of the files that are actually in the `mesonet` folder? Please edit your question to show that (just a few of them, if there are many). What do you mean by *I need the code to be exactly like this for my project*?

Comment: If you want `site` and `150` to be subfolders then you're missing file separators (slashes) in your concatenated string. Otherwise the error is exactly what it says, the file cannot be found. Add a breakpoint and look at what the file name is you're asking MATLAB to find, i.e. the stuff in the square brackets.